# How to solve an unexpect std::allocator when compile code？

Tags: c++, googletest, allocator

I defined a constructor of a class as below:

```
struct TestClass
{
    TestClass(std::uint8_t, std::vector<Type>)
    {
        //...
    }
};
```

Then I want to use google test to do a unit test, the compile error occurs when I try to construct an instance of TestClass, as below:

```
TEST(name1,name2)
{
    //...
    Type element;
    std::vector<Type> lst{element};
    TestClass instance(0, lst);
    //...
}
```

The gnu compiler reports:

> "In function `name1_name2_Test::TestBody()':test.cpp:(.text+0x165d): undefined reference to`TestClass::TestClass(signed char, std::vector< Type, std::allocator< Type>)'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Below is my evironment:

> g++ version: 5.3.0
>   google test version: 1.7.0
>   the compile command: g++ -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 test.cpp -std=c++14 -lboost_system  -lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread

Have you ever met similar problem? Please give me some suggestions, thanks.

Below code can cause above error:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

struct Element
{
    Element(const std::vector<std::uint8_t>& element) : element_(element){}
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> element_;
};

using ElementList = std::vector<Element>;

struct Information
{
    Information(std::uint8_t, ElementList) {}
    std::int8_t number_;
    ElementList eleLst_;
};

TEST(name1,name2)
{
    std::uint8_t number = 0;

    std::vector<std::uint8_t> vec{1,2,3,4};
    Element elem(vec);
    ElementList lst{elem};

    Information info(std::int8_t(0), lst);                      //false
}
GTEST_API_ int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Below is compile message:

> /tmp/ccUzsTfz.o: In function `name1_name2_Test::TestBody()':
>   test.cpp:(.text+0x130): undefined reference to`Information::Information(unsigned char, std::vector< Element, std::allocator< Element > >)'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: sorry, because of the confidentiality agreement, I cannot show you the complete code. And in my opinion, above error message is enough to describe my situation and you should have the ability to understand the problem. (Above code is an abstract model of my original code)

Comment: @ChenDong Not the complete code, but the **minimal** code that still shows the same error.

Comment: No it is not enough. First it is not even the full build message, but I guess it came in the link phase. That means that the error may be in definition of TestClass or may be in the way you use it. And are you sure that uint8_t and signed char are the same type (and not simply have same representation) on your system?

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/3545273/serge-ballesta    Yes, I update a minimal code. Please help me to solve this problem,

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/4672588/cpplearner   Yes, I update a minimal code. Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your signature is:

```
struct TestClass
{
    TestClass(std::uint8_t, std::vector<Type>)
    {
        //...
    }
};
```

And the LINKER looks for:

```
TestClass::TestClass(signed char, std::vector< Type>, std::allocator< Type>);
```

Your TestClass' constructor definition does not contain an allocator-parameter!

That's why there's no function instantiated containing the allocator-parameter and consequently it is not found by the linker.

### EDIT: Some more reference

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/ // Basics

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors // Good to know

### EDIT: There was some misunderstanding

```
TestClass(signed char, std::vector<Type>)
```

as the constructor is enough, if you use a standard allocator of type "Type"..

See:
http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

THis is the signature of the class:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class vector;
```

As you can see, it has a default template parameter assignment for Allocator, which is std::allocator.

This way, you only have to specify an allocator In the template parameter list, if you have a custom allocator, i.e.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Type {};

template <typename T>
class MyBatchAllocator {

};

template <typename TAllocator = std::allocator<Type>>
class TestClass {
    public:
        TestClass(signed char, const std::vector<Type, TAllocator>&) {
            // ...
    }
};

int main()
{
    // main.cpp
    Type element;
    std::vector<Type, MyBatchAllocator<Type>> lst({ element });
    TestClass<MyBatchAllocator<Type>> tc(0, lst);
}
```

Otherwise, if you use standard allocators use this:

```
int main() {
    Type element;
    std::vector<Type> lst2({ element });
    TestClass<> tc2(0, lst2); 
    // Yes, if TestClass is a template with a single 
    // defaulted template parameter the empty <> are required.
}
```

### Appendix

If you want to make your life with those templates easier, you could employ an alias:

```
using DefaultTestClass = TestClass<>;
```

and call it like:

```
DefaultTestClass tc3(0, lst2);
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Comment: From the compiler's message, I used TestClass::TestClass(signed char, std::vector< Type>, std::allocator< Type>) rather than TestClass::TestClass(signed char, std::vector< Type>).

Comment: Yes, but the linker can't find one with that signature. :D

Comment: And If I reload a constructor like "TestClass(std::vector<Type>,std::uint8_t)", and use "TestClass instance(lst, 0)",  there is no error.

Comment: Yes, because now you pass in two parameters to the constructor with matching types, not 3. @Chen Dong see edit above please.

Comment: Yes, so what should I do?

Comment: Read the above two links from the edit and you will know what to do :D

Comment: I'm sorry that I post a wrong message, and now I correct it. And the error message is "undefined reference toTestClass::TestClass(signed char, std::vector< Type, std::allocator< Type>)", it's not 3 parameters, but 2.